# How can I customize the text for Android app sharing

Tags: android

I added my Android app to the group of the apps that appears on the share menu, so I can get data from external apps.

Now how can I customize the small text that appears? The default is the app name.

For example for Reddit app it says: ***Post on Reddit***.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml`, inside the activity tag that handles your intent add a `android:label` tag. Like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:label="Label to show">
    <intent-filter>
        <!--Your intent filter-->
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: I have only one MainActivity, because my app is in React Native, and if I change the android:label, also the app name change. I need to change only in share menu.

App name: XXXXXX
Share menu: Share to XXXXXX